# Python, named tuple, expanding on making a basic part invntory system

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been using this basic code for a simple inventory system. I need to expand this to keep track of another list of parts that are leaving the inventory. I thought I might be able to do this by creating another namedtuple for the data structure . I have some problems because the two namedtuples would need to exist and be accessed at the same time. How can I do this in python?

`` import sys
from collections import namedtuple


class Part(namedtuple("Part", "name part_number quantity")):
    def __str__(self):
        return ", ".join(self)


class Parts(dict):
    def display (self):
        if not self:
            print('No Parts Found in List')
            return
        print()
        print('Name, Part Number, Quantity')
        for part in self.values():
            print(part)
        print()

    def add(self, *args):
        try:
            name, part_number, quantity = args
        except ValueError:
            name = input("Enter Name of Part:\n ")
            part_number = input("Enter Part Number:\n ")
            quantity = input("Enter Quantity:\n ")
        self[name] = Part(name, part_number, quantity)

    def remove(self, part=""):
        if not part:
            part = input("Enter Part Name to Remove\n")
        try:
            del self[part]
        except Keyerror:
            print("Part {} not found.".format(part))

    def edit(self, part=""):
        if not part:
            part = input("Enter Part Name to Edit\n")
        try:
            new_name = input("Enter new part name\n")
            number = input("Enter new part number\n ")
            quantity = input("Enter new quantity\n ")
            self[part] = Part(new_name, number, quantity)
        except KeyError:
            print("No such Part exists: {}".format(part))

    def save(self, filename=""):
        if not filename:
            filename = input("Filename to save: ")
        with open(filename, "wt") as out_file:
            for part in self.values():
                out_file.write("{}\n".format(part))
        print("File saved")

    def load(self, filename=""):
        if not filename:
            filename = input("Filename to load: ")
        try:
            with open(filename, "rt") as in_file:
                for line in in_file:
                    if not line:
                        break
                    part, part_number, quantity = line.strip().split(",")
                    self.add(part, part_number, quantity)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print("File Not Found.")


def menu(inventory):
    menu_list = [("Parts", inventory.display),
                 ("Add Part", inventory.add),
                 ("Remove Part", inventory.remove),
                 ("Edit Part", inventory.edit),
                 ("Save Part List", inventory.save),
                 ("Load Part List", inventory.load),
                 ("Exit", sys.exit)]
    while True:
        for i, (name, _) in enumerate(menu_list, 1):
            print("{}. {}".format(i, name))
        try:
            user = int(input("Selection> "))
            menu_list[user-1][1]()
        except (ValueError, IndexError):
            print("Selection Not Valid.")

def main():
    print("Welcome to Sticks&Stones Inventory System")
    inventory = Parts()
    while True:
        menu(inventory)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        print("Exiting Program...")`enter code here ``

`

Comment: As an aside, inheriting from `dict` seems... not like a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Your two tuples (or more) can exist and be accessed at the same time, with no problem!

```
class Parts(namedtuple("Parts", "name part_number quantity")):
    def __str__(self):
        return ", ".join(self)

class RemovedParts(namedtuple("RemovedParts", "name quantity")):
    pass

# etc.
```

With that said, let me make some suggestions:

1. As @juanpa.arrivillaga has already suggested, your current `Parts` class should not extend `dict`. Ask yourself, "does my system *have* a dictionary because it's convenient to the implementation, or *is* my system a dictionary because of some fundamental property?"

   I think you'll see that the has-a/is-a question in this case is a pretty good way to see that you should use composition (has-a) rather than inheritance (is-a) in your design.
2. Consider renaming your `Parts` class to something different. What you're modeling is really a thing that contains information about the parts, and how many you have on hand. Perhaps `PartsInfo` or even `Inventory` would be a better class name.
3. Consider separating the actual management object from the user interface. Perhaps you have an `Inventory` object and an `InventoryUI` object? Move pretty much all of the functions that interact with the user into the UI class.
4. Write some helper functions (methods) to do things like read in part numbers or part names and confirm that they are valid. Maybe you need a pair of dictionaries, one for part-number -> part-info and the other for part-name -> part-info?
5. Consider using the `json` library to serialize your data for load/save operations.